# How to extend TextAreaFor in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, extension-methods

I know how to extend TextBoxFor :

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
        {
            MvcHtmlString html = default(MvcHtmlString);
            RouteValueDictionary routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);         
            html = System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(htmlHelper, expression, routeValues);
            return html;
        }
```

I want to do the same for TextAreaFor but unfortunately **System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions** dose not contain the TextAreaFor method. How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703546%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), it's in `TextAreaExtensions` static class

```
return System.Web.Mvc.Html.TextAreaExtensions.TextAreaFor(htmlHelper, expression, routeValues);
```

or just

```
return htmlHelper.TextAreaFor(expression, routeValues);
```

by the way, the third argument is just (as in TextBoxFor) a `IDictionary<string, Object> htmlAttributes`, nothing to do with RouteValues.

It's just working because `RouteValueDictionary` implements `IDictionary<string, Object>`, but your arguments are confusing.

Comment: I need the RouteValueDictionary because html Attributes comes as an anonymous object. I didn't wrote the code here, but the extension needs to add more attributes.

Comment: @YaronLevi what I say is just that you don't need a RouteValueDictionary. An `IDictionary<string, Object>` would do the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you tag your property with `[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]` and then use `EditorFor` you should get your wanted result.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
```

Comment: I tried a lot to found the difference between `TextAreaFor` and `Html.EditorFor`. Can you give a short on line answer. please ?

Comment: EditorFor will render based on teh attributes of the given property it is called for, whether that is a textbox (string), checkbox (bool), etc - or which one you specify, while TextAreaFor will always render a TextBox.

Comment: Drop down can also be rendered automatically by editor but how check box will be rendered automatically?